# Is there a default limit on request message size in NuSoap?

Tags: nusoap

Is there a default limit on request message size in NuSoap? I am asking this because when I send CSV data with size 194 KB using NuSOAP client to a NuSOAP server I get the following response from the server.

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2012 04:36:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

I have tried looking at the error log files for apache and PHP, but nothing can be found there.
I have been fighting with the issue for a few hours. And I have tried searching around for an answer. Some posts recommended increasing the memory limit in php.ini I did that with no luck. Your help is greatly appreciated.

--Abdul

Answer (score 0):

I think message size will be limited rather by a PHP memory limit, than by some hardcoded value. At least I could send a 6.5MB string without any problems. When I tried to send a 8MB string I got an out of memory exception inside nusoap.php (my server has 64MB limit for PHP).